# MS-Access SQL loops

Tags: sql, ms-access, loops

I would like to apply a for loop in this sql statement in ms-access something like:

```
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
UPDATE current_stock SET current_stock.quantity = DLookup("quantity","current_stock","stock_id=i")-DLookup("req_quantity","Bom_dell","lap_id=(SELECT lap_id FROM laptop_info WHERE model_name='Dell Inspiron')" And "stock_id=i")
WHERE stock_id=1;
}
```

Please advise if there is any method  in MS-access to be able to do something similar to a for loop using sql queries.

---

**Bom_dell**

```
bom_id lap_id stock_id req_quantity
1         1       1        1
2         1       2        3
3         1       3        6
4         1       4        1
5         1       5        1
6         1       6        2
7         2       7        7
8         2       8        8
9         2       9        1
10        2      10        1
11        2      11        1
12        2      12        3
```

**current_stock**

```
ID lap_id stock_id quantity
1     1       1        11
2     1       2        11
3     1       3        11
```

**lap_info**

```
lap_id model_name     model_num price
1      Dell Inspiron  INS81     35000
2      Dell XLS       XL91      24000
```

**Sample query**

```
UPDATE (SELECT laptop_info.model_name, current_stock.stock_id, Bom_dell.req_quantity, current_stock.quantity
FROM (current_stock INNER JOIN laptop_info ON current_stock.lap_id = laptop_info.lap_id) INNER JOIN Bom_dell ON current_stock.stock_id = Bom_dell.stock_id)

SET quantity=quantity-req_quantity
WHERE stock_id BETWEEN 1 AND 3
AND model_name='Dell Inspiron'
```

---

[image: laptop info]
[image: current stock]
[image: bom_dell]

```
UPDATE (SELECT laptop_info.model_name, current_stock.stock_id, Bom_dell.req_quantity, current_stock.quantity
FROM (current_stock INNER JOIN laptop_info ON current_stock.lap_id = laptop_info.lap_id) INNER JOIN Bom_dell ON current_stock.stock_id = Bom_dell.stock_id) SET quantity = quantity-req_quantity
WHERE stock_id BETWEEN 1 AND 3
AND model_name IN ([Forms]![Invoice1]![laptop_id])
```

Comment: you should be able to do what you are looking to do with a set based operation.  instead of using "where stock_id = i" use something like "where stockID >=0 and stockID <=8"

Comment: SELECT (quantity-req_quantity) FROM current_stock,Bom_dell WHERE (current_stock.stock_id >=0 and current_stock.stock_id <=3) AND (Bom_dell.lap_id=1 AND (Bom_dell.stock_id>=0 and Bom_dell.stock_id<=3))

Comment: this query is doing the job but it is repeating as
16
16
16
14
14
14
11
11
11

Comment: I want it to do something similar to 1 column matrix substraction

Comment: Please advise...as your set based operation method seems promising..thank you

Comment: Three questions on the same topic 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925943/ms-access-sql-loops http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932054/selecting-and-updating-from-the-same-table#comment12680553_9932054
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931037/want-to-do-matrix-style-substraction-between-columns-in-ms-access-database ?

Comment: @Sweta Dwivedi That's okay everyone starts somewhere, I flagged the post below for deletion as it is not an answer and I have added some more SQL to my answer. See how you get on.

Comment: Dear Remou, Thank fully your first query you posted has worked fine with some changes as per table data in the sample query above... your idea has worked like charm...i would like your help in passing form value to model_name. I have been trying to do this but to no help! please advise..my code is below:

Comment: UPDATE (SELECT laptop_info.model_name, current_stock.stock_id, Bom_dell.req_quantity, current_stock.quantity
FROM (current_stock INNER JOIN laptop_info ON current_stock.lap_id = laptop_info.lap_id) INNER JOIN Bom_dell ON current_stock.stock_id = Bom_dell.stock_id)  AS [%$##@_Alias] SET quantity = quantity-req_quantity
WHERE stock_id BETWEEN 1 AND 9
AND model_name IN ([Forms]![Invoice1]![laptop_id])

Comment: IN is not going to work. You would have to build the query string in VBA if you want a list of items. If it is one model_name, use `= [Forms]![Invoice1]![laptop_id]`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for something on the lines of:

```
UPDATE (current_stock 
INNER JOIN laptop_info ON laptop_info.stock_id=current_stock.stock_id)
INNER JOIN Bom_dell ON Bom_dell.lap_id = laptop_info.lap_id
SET current_stock.quantity = current_stock.quantity - Bom_dell.req_quantity
WHERE stock_id Between 1 And 8 
AND model_name='Dell Inspiron'
```

---

Try this. I have used aliases - a is for the current_stock table and b is for the sub query. This assumes that you have one line per stock id in bom_dell.

```
UPDATE current_stock AS a 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT bom_dell.stock_id, lap_info.model_name, bom_dell.req_quantity
   FROM bom_dell 
   INNER JOIN lap_info ON bom_dell.lap_id = lap_info.lap_id
   WHERE (((bom_dell.stock_id) Between 1 And 3) 
   AND ((lap_info.model_name)="Dell Inspiron")))  AS b 
ON a.Stock_id = b.Stock_id SET a.quantity = [a].[quantity]+[b].[req_quantity];
```

Comment: Dear Remou, i would like your kind attention to this problem also please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932054/selecting-and-updating-from-the-same-table

Comment: UPDATE current_stock 
SET quantity = (
    SELECT (quantity-req_quantity) 
    FROM current_stock, Bom_dell 
    WHERE (current_stock.stock_id >=0 and current_stock.stock_id <=3) 
      AND (Bom_dell.lap_id=1 
      AND (Bom_dell.stock_id>=0 and Bom_dell.stock_id<=3) 
      AND current_stock.stock_id = bom_dell.stock_id)
    )
WHERE stock_id >=0 
AND stock_id <=3;

Comment: Dear remou, I would like to do the above operation in ms-access but it is giving me the error: Operation not updateable. Please advise..

Comment: You cannot set the value to a subquery like that in Access. In my sample query, I use joins. You need to post some sample data from the relevant tables and some notes on what you want to happen. Just edit your question to include the information.

Comment: Also, did you try my sample query and what was the outcome?

Comment: http://a6.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/544828_332396220150571_100001405884724_936210_1252086241_n.jpg

This is the relationship of my tables

Comment: Okay, and where is the sample data for the tables you are interested in, the outline of the result you want and the comment on how my sample query did or did not work? `:)

Comment: SELECT model_name, current_stock.stock_id,req_quantity, quantity FROM ((current_stock
INNER JOIN laptop_info ON laptop_info.lap_id=current_stock.lap_id) INNER JOIN Bom_dell ON current_stock.stock_id=Bom_dell.stock_id)

Comment: Dear Remou, I have made changes to your submitted query to match my table data. As well as I have added a lap_id field to current_stock table...I have posted the query just above this comment for you to see.. I have successfully created the join..now I have to use this query with UPDATE and your SET condition for it to work..I tried using your SET condition but as it is copied ,it didn't work..probabaly you can make a suggestion of UPDATE-SET condition based on the above query which I rearranged from yours query,looking forward to your reply and as well as trying myself to implement your idea.

Comment: I really do not understand why you do not edit you own post to add sample table data as I have asked. Is it that you not understand what it is I am asking?